# Upload list of ZIP codes to categorize accounts

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, import, upload

I'm a VERY new user of Salesforce, with experience in SQL and SAS/Stata. I think what I'm trying to do is simple - the company I'm volunteering for has several hundred client accounts in Salesforce, each of which has a (US) ZIP code. The company has provided me a very small file containing ~100 ZIP codes that indicate something simple - let's say it's all ZIP codes for rural areas in a state. I would just like to upload the file and merge it with each account, by ZIP, to flag whether the account is in a rural area.

When I try to read in the file via Data Importer, it seems like my only two options are to to merge by account or Salesforce ID, neither of which are in the list of ZIP codes (obviously).

I've Googled a good bit, looked for similar questions in Stack Exchange and have begun taking the Trailhead lessons, but I think my lack of knowledge of Salesforce terminology is slowing my search. I'm certain this is something Salesforce can do easily.

I appreciate any advice or links to existing solutions.

Comment: You should export accounts from salesforce using dataloader and when exporting select salesforce id, zip code and the flag you want to update. On the extracted file, do a vlookup with the zip codes you have and the accounts you extracted and then do upload with the dataloader.

Comment: @javanoob -- Thanks so much for the quick reply. I think this would be a great trick if the company had a static set of accounts; however, they add accounts on a regular basis. I'm hoping there's some way for me to upload the file and save it to Salesforce -- like a crosswalk or dim table -- then create a custom field based on some sort of array formula that will dynamically flag accounts based on their ZIP code. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. How many zip codes you have? If the number is huge, you should write a trigger or something to update the custom field on the account as soon as it is added based on the reference list of zip code values(stored in a different object)..

Comment: Very small list of ZIPs -- only ~100. My first barrier is that I can't seem to figure out the very simple step of uploading the list. The way I've tried (Data Importer) asks me for a key field to merge the file by, but the only options provided are Salesforce ID or Account ID. I really think I just want to upload this as a standalone file (object?), then create a link by ZIP once it's in Salesforce.

Comment: You need to create a new custom object just to store these zip codes and load the zip code values into that object and then you have to write a trigger on the Account object. With all this, what will happen is every time an account is inserted, the code will look at the zip code of the account and then looks into the zip code custom object you created and sets the field on the account object. To do all this, you need to be able to write Apex code. I would suggest you to start with salesforce trial head on triggers and post here any specific questions you run into. People are happy to help.